# Add multiple lines on a 3d plotly graph (more than 100 lines)

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

Always with my Lorenz model :)

I made a code to integrate the lorenz model with a lot of different initial conditions using Rcpp to increase the overall speed. Besides, all my data are stored in a huge data frame of 1.000.000 lines and 5 columns. The first 4 columns respectively contain time, X1, X2 and X3 (3 variables) and the fifth one is an index which corresponds to the id of the initial condition (see the link below)

[my_data_frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TVB3.png)

x=1 corresponds to the first initial condition, x = 2, to the second initial condition ... until x = 100 for example.

Everything is embedded in a shinyapp and I encounter some problems with the plotly package. Indeed I would like to add each trajectory on the same 3d plot, without doing it manually for each initial condition. For example, I did that:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(out[out$x == 1,], x = out[out$x==1, 2], y = out[out$x==1, 3],
              z = out[out$x==1, 4], type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
              line = list(width = 4)) %>%
  add_trace(x = out[out$x==2, 2], y = out[out$x==2, 3], z = out[out$x==2, 4]) %>%
  add_trace(x = out[out$x==10, 2], y = out[out$x==10, 3], z = out[out$x==10, 4]) %>%
  add_trace(x = out[out$x==6, 2], y = out[out$x==6, 3], z = out[out$x==6, 4])
```

which produces the following plot for 4 different initial states:

[my_plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsKB6.png)

I would like to use a for loop instead or another method (because I am supposed to plot about 1000 trajectories). I tried:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(out[out$x == 1,], x = out[out$x==1, 2], y = out[out$x==1, 3],
              z = out[out$x==1, 4], type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
              line = list(width = 4))
for (i in 2:nrow(state())){
     p2 <- add_trace(p2, x = out[out$x==i, 2], y = out[out$x==i, 3], z = out[out$x==i, 4])
   }
```

where nrow(state()) gives me the number of initial conditions. This produces an error:
     **Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "NULL"**.

Thus I really don't know what to do with that... Moreover does somebody know how to do that without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your data, I can only guess that the error is occurring because `i` is taking a value which results in an empty subset.

Use `split` to separate your traces.

```
library(plotly)
```

Data for example. I chosen column names (x, v1, v2, v3) as I don't know yours.

```
out = data.frame(x = rep(c(1,2,10,6), each = 10), v1 = runif(40), v2 = runif(40), v3 = runif(40))

str(out)

'data.frame':   40 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ v1: num  0.899 0.929 0.976 0.687 0.503 ...
 $ v2: num  0.5851 0.9568 0.7853 0.5826 0.0658 ...
 $ v3: num  0.3803 0.4961 0.0111 0.7265 0.9474 ...
```

You'll need to replace `~v2 ~v2 ~v3` with your column names. Note the `split` parameter

```
p3 <- plot_ly(out, x = ~v1, y = ~v2, z = ~v3, split = ~x, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
              line = list(width = 4))
p3
```

No where near as pretty as yours, but hopefully helpful.

[image]

Comment: I tried you code and it works! Split is very useful. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

According to **Jeremy Voisey**, the answer is:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(out, x = out[, 2], y = out[, 3],
              z = out[, 4], split = ~x, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
              line = list(width = 4))
```

Simple and efficient!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWxin.png)